How to generate background color like this with jQuery?
how I can generate a similar background image with jquery?

Thanks!

Have you made any initial attempts at all, where are you stuck?



$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('monCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Créer un dégradé
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'green');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'yellow');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue');

    // Appliquer le dégradé comme fond
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="monCanvas"></canvas>




I love it how French people just casually talk to strangers in French, assuming they'd speak it too. Bro, French is no English.

I apologize for the oversight. Let me provide the response in English:
To generate a similar background image using jQuery, you can utilize the HTML5 canvas element and draw the desired patterns with JavaScript. Here’s an example code snippet to get you started:

Make sure to replace the canvas content with your own code. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

Please put this into your post, not the comment :)

Thanks! How to draw non linear gradients? But curves or waves...
